# System properties showing only 2.75 gb ram instead of 4gb

Tags: windows-10, memory

I am using windows 10 and i am trying to install adobe xd software.recently i upgraded my system ram to 2 gb to 4gb just to install this software.

after upgrading the system to 4gb, i am able to see only 2.75 gb in installed memory and because of this i am unable to install Adobe xd software.

any idea how can i utilize the full ram of 4gb so that it shows 4gb ram and so that i can install the software.

Comment: Are you using a 32 bit version of Windows? The only way around this limitation is to install a 64-bit version, but you must so a clean install, there is no way to upgrade from 32 to 64 bit.

Comment: @Mokubai I'd post that as the answer...

Comment: @djsmiley2k - There are numerous existing duplicates to this question though.

Comment: Depends on your hardware as well as your version of Windows 10.

Version? Is it 32-bit or 64-bit? Click on the Windows icon (normally at lower left}, then the Gear icon. Choose System, then About. Is the system type 64-bit operating system? If not, you're capped at 4GB usable memory, and your hardware will use some of that memory space (e.g., video adapter), reducing it further.

Comment: Glad it worked after installing the 64 bit OS.